# Generating discrete vectors in a difference of cubes space

Tags: c++, random, vector, multidimensional-array

I want to generate random discrete valued vectors in a space. The simple instance was a follows; a cube. In this instance each coefficient of the vector had to be in between two values, so that it is inside the multi-dimensional cube. This cube can be described by it's two corner points (stored in points[0] and points[1]). I programmed this in C++(11) as follows:

```
random_device rd;
mt19937 eng(rd());
vector<uniform_int_distribution<>> distr;
for(int i = 0; i< points[0].size();i++){
 distr.push_back(uniform_int_distribution<>(point[0].at(i),points[1].at(i)));
}
for(int i = 0;i<trials;i++){
 vector<unsigned> draw;
 for(int j = 0; j< points[0].size();j++){
  draw.push_back(distr.at(j)(eng));
 }
 // Do stuff with vector
}
```

This code runs fine. Now however instead of a cube, I have to generate a vector inside the difference of two cubes. So we have the two corner points of the large cube, and a point inside the large cube that combined with EITHER the top OR bottom corner of the large cube induces a cube in which I don't want the vector to lie.

My first instinct was to generate vectors as before and then filtering out those that are in the small cube. If however the small cube is rather large, then it will take too much time to generate the amount of trials I want. Does someone here have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried how much time that would exactly take? I know such "rinse, reroll and repeat" thingies might be scary, but if that's not a part of something performance-critical...

Comment: No, I shall implement it and check back

Comment: There's a [piecewise constant distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution); unfortunately, it's for floating-point values. Maybe it isn't so hard to create a piecewise uniform distribution for ints?

Comment: What pieces would you suggest I divide up the space in?

Answer (score 0):

I think that first you need to define what that third point is, i.e.: say that your initial cube is (point[0],point[1]) and that the third point is point[2]. Do you want to sample in the difference between (point[0],point[1]) and (point[0],point[2]) or in the difference between (point[0],point[1]) and (point[2],point[1])?

Accordingly, I would change the call to the ctor `uniform_int_distribution<>(point[0].at(i),points[1].at(i)))` to `uniform_int_distribution<>(point[2].at(i),points[1].at(i)))` or to `uniform_int_distribution<>(point[0].at(i),points[2].at(i)))`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this doesn't work, because in multiple dimension the set of vectors: (inducedby(points[0],points[1])\setminus inducedby(points[0],points[2])) is not the same as inducedby(points[2],points[1]).